# React Native App throwing Error like TypeError: dispatcher.useSyncExternalStore is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, zustand

I am working on React native app using zustand for global state management. Before It is working fine bt now it thrwing error..such as
TypeError: dispatcher.useSyncExternalStore is not a function. (In 'dispatcher.useSyncExternalStore(subscribe, getSnapshot, getServerSnapshot)', 'dispatcher.useSyncExternalStore' is undefined)

```js
{
  "name": "main",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/roboto": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.5",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.2",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.3.0",
    "expo-font": "^10.0.5",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "^0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.12.0",
    "react-native-step-indicator": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.8",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "zustand": "^4.0.0-beta.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Icuv.png)